# ASP.Net Core docker environment variable to deactivate SSL redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

is there also an environment variable to deactivate a SSL redirect like it is able to set other ASPNETCORE variables within a docker container?
similar to these:

```
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
  - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=<pass>
  - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/usr/<path>/aspnetapp.pfx
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET Core HTTPS redirection is usually configured in code. In fact, it is a [recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#require-https) for doing this in production web apps.

So the easiest way to do activation/deactivation would probably be to tie this code to the type of environment you are building it in.

So, in the `Configure` method of your `Startup` class, you can do something like this:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    // Just don't.
}
else
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Otherwise, you could introduce your own variable and read its value during configuration:

```cs
var httpsRedirectEnabled =
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_CUSTOM_HTTPS_REDIRECT") == "true";

if (httpsRedirectEnabled)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Mind you, this is not the best way for string comparisson, but it'll work in a pinch.